# Joomla automatic parse and format from url

Tags: plugins, joomla1.5

How can I approach a Joomla plugin (I assume) that can parse and format an article sort of like Facebook does when posting a url? Does one exist or is it a large undertaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you want a plugin that reads a url and displays contents from the url's webpage ? If thats the case, you can build your own plugin using an api from http://www.alchemyapi.com.

see their demo at http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/demo.html